# Does Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition include an inbuilt TFS Server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to make source control for my web application, I have VS 2010 Ultimate editioin, does it include a TFS Server inbuilt, or I need to install it separately ?

Comment: This is a good question and a good idea. I wouldn't mind a TFS Express :) I use GIT in the mean time.

Comment: @DustinDavis: Default, standard TFS 2010 install uses SQL Server Express and can install on client OS: probably as close as we'll get to "TFS Express". (Advanced mode is needed to use full SQL Server, reporting and SharePoint.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TFS is a separate application.

Comment: And note the TFS licence goes with an MSDN subscription (Professional and up levels). Ie. retail VS doesn't include TFS; but VS+MSDN >=Pro *does*. (I might have the precise edition requirements from memory: check.)